# How to export multiple files in the loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data problem because I cant write them to file, i want to use loop for

```
file_1 <- dane[as.Date(dane$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d") > as.Date('2016-12-31') & as.Date(dane$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d") <= as.Date('2017-07-02'),]
file_2 <- dane[as.Date(dane$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d") > as.Date('2017-07-02') & as.Date(dane$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d") <= as.Date('2017-12-31'),]
file_3 <- dane[as.Date(dane$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d") > as.Date('2017-12-31') & as.Date(dane$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d") <= as.Date('2018-07-02'),]


for (ii in 1:23){
name <- paste("file_", ii)
write.xlsx(name[ii], file = "./test/test.xlsx", sheetname = name, append = TRUE)
}
```

Data in file_1 looks like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq8Z4.png)

I dont know how can i solve it.

Comment: Yeah, just off the bat, ```name``` is a vector of length = 1, so ```name[ii] ``` is not going to do what you want it to do.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here, so it's hard to answer without added clarification. Do you want to write 3 different .xlsx files? Do you want to append the 3 file objects in 1 file? If so, why don't you append them into 1 data frame outside of the write.xls() function?

Comment: Instead of `write.xlsx(name[ii], ...)` use `write.xlsx(get(name), ...)`.

Comment: I want to append them into 1 file, but i dont know how to get variable file_1, file_2 and file_1 and Save them

Comment: If they all contain the same columns, which it appears they do, read them all in, rbind, write it out. you can even do a loop read, rbind then write it out. Basically I'm saying way @divibisan just said.